# I have an existing artifactory oss install. I want a new install. But it is not adding the "libs-release" and "libs-snapshot" repositories

Tags: ubuntu, artifactory

All servers are Ubuntu 22.04 and I am using the OSS artifactory apt repo from jfrog.

I have a VM with artifactory installed on it.  For various reasons I need to replace that VM with a new one.

I installed artifactory on the new VM.  I was encountering a problem, can't remember what it was.  So I purged artifactory and installed it again.  Now it does not go through initial setup (changing the admin password, etc).  The libs-release and libs-snapshot repos are not present.

How do I get it to go through the initial setup again, where I change the password and tell it to use Maven?

Comment: I tried finding every directory and file on the system with 'jfrog' or 'artifactory' in the name and removing it and rebooting before trying the install again.  It will not do the initial setup or create the repos I want.

Comment: If  manually create libs-release, it does not act as a cache for maven central.  And once I create a repository, there is no way for me to delete it.  It's a brand new install, I haven't changed ANY settings.

Comment: Now it's too late to get anything from the old VM.  It's gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to do the initial setup.  Instead of going through my haproxy install using the canonical URL that I have planned for it, I browsed directly to hostname:8081 and then it all worked.  Which is odd because I did get the initial setup to work the first time even through the proxy.

Then even that didn't work for another reinstall.

Ultimately I did get it to work.  What's critical is accessing the current install, clearing the browser cache, and clearing all browsing data for the last hour (which is an option in Chrome but not Firefox).  Incognito mode (Chrome) or Private Browsing (Firefox) also works.

Comment: Now that isn't working any more.  I started over because I am trying to also incorporate xray, but it looks like it might not be possible to run xray without paying jfrog for a license.  So here we are with another brand new artifactory install that refuses to do the initial setup.

Comment: I got it to do the initial setup once.  But now I can't get it to run again.

Comment: It is at the /ui/admin/onboarding-page on port 8082.  but it's not asking me for a new admin password like it does when the initial setup runs.

Comment: I did figure out how to create repos.  There is a "quick repository setup" option on the user dropdown at the upper right.  But it creates all the repos with a prefix, and I do not want them to have a prefix.  I want the defaults, with names like `libs-release` and `libs-snapshot`.

Comment: I am doing this "reinstall" dance so frequently that I created a "nuke_artifactory" script to delete everything and reboot.

Comment: Another annoying issue:  I cannot delete or rename repos.  So it has this "example-repo-local" repo that is going to be around forever and I cannot do anything about it.